# Python component builder from C++ objects in cython

Tags: cython

I'm trying to find how can I make a python *builder* using C++ objects in cython. I try to summarize the code in an equivalent example. (I couldn't find how to use the __init__() and __cinit__() to give the pointers and C variables, and I'm duing a setter/getter *bypass*.)

```py
cdef extern from "device.h":
    cdef cppclass CDevice

cdef class PyDevice:
    cdef CDevice* _cdevice
    #(...)
    cdef SetDevice(CDevice* cdevice):
        self._cdevice = cdevice
    #(...)

cdef extern from "component.h":
    cdef cppclass CComponent

cdef class PyComponent:
    cdef CComponent _ccomponent
    #(...)
    cdef CComponent GetComponent(self):
        return self._ccomponent
    #(...)

cdef extern from "builder.h":
    cdef cppclass CBuilder:
        CDevice* BuildDevice(CComponent&) except+

cdef class PyBuilder:
    cdef CBuilder* _cbuilder
    #(...)
    def BuildDevice(self,pyComponent):
        pydevice = PyDevice()
        pydevice.SetDevice(self._cbuilder.BuildDevice(pyComponent.GetComponent()))
    #(...)
```

The issue I can see from the compilation error, is the returning from "GetComponent()" seems to become a Python Object instead of a "Component" object. May you see where is the detail that make wrong?

Comment: Is it just `CComponent` has two Cs at the start but `cdef Component GetComponent(self):` only has one?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo mistake writing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
def BuildDevice(self,pyComponent):
```

to

```
def BuildDevice(self,PyComponent pyComponent):
```

since it doesn't know the type of the argument that you passed (at compile time), it can't tell that the call `pyComponent.GetComponent()` should call the `cdef` function and thus it doesn't know that it returns the C object.

Comment: That's great! Many thanks. I didn't know that I could do that in 'def' method, I thought it was only for 'cdef'.

Comment: You can - it just adds a type check when you call it so if you called it with an `int` for example you'd get an exception.